# KerasTuner takes forever to finish

Tags: python, keras, hyperparameters

I have a Keras model that I wanted to tune using KerasTuner.

I ran the tuner and it continued to run for 15 days before I had to stop it manually.

What am I doing incorrectly?

**Model**

```
def _model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(36)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            hp.Int("hidden_layer_1", min_value=32, max_value=2048, step=32, default=128),
            activation="sigmoid"
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        hp.Int("hidden_layer_2", min_value=32, max_value=2048, step=32, default=128),
        activation="sigmoid"
    ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
            hp.Choice("learning_rate", values=[1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3])
        ),
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics="categorical_accuracy"
    )
    return model
```

**Tuner Code**

```
    tuner = Hyperband(
        _model,
        objective='val_categorical_accuracy',
        factor=3,
        max_epochs=EPOCH_SIZE,
        directory="_tuner_hyperband_directory_",
        project_name="_tuner_hyperband_project_name_",
    )
    tuner.search_space_summary()
    tuner.search(
        train_x,
        train_y,
        epochs=EPOCH_SIZE,
        validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y)
    )
    models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)
    print(models[0].summary())
```